# How to create a view with transparent half-circles in it, and add shadow

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I need to create a ticket in an app, like the image that I've attached.
My problem is, that I can't seem to find a solution to make the transparent half-circle-holes, meanwhile making the shadows follow the hole.

[image: Ticket view]

The ticketview is going to used in a tableview cell.

My first thought was to make two views, one white, and one green, and then add some background-coloured circular views on the green part - but then the shadow won't look right.

Then I thought about adding it as an image, but I just think this solution is wrong, and not very iOS-developer-ish.. Also this won't scale right on different devices, and I won't be able to align text to the green part etc.

So I'm a little lost - how to fix this job?

Comment: I would go with images if you could. Drawing things like this is overkill compared to providing a graphic. If you absolutely can't get graphics you could do this with bezier paths. For shadowing with your created view, you then get the CGPath of the view, and draw a shadow along the curve using bezier paths: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/BezierPaths/BezierPaths.html

Comment: @NicolaiHarbo Where you need to show shadow

Answer (score 1):

**Please follow the steps to solved your problem:**

1. Take on UIView in you cell - Green view in your case
2. Add two subviews into it
3. One on top right and other on bottom right (Add Only half view in top right - remaining half portion of view must be out of your green view)
4. Add below code to set make it semi circular...

   ```
   firstCircleView.layer.cornerRadius = firstCircleView.frame.size.width + 2
   firstCircleView.clipsToBounds = true
   firstCircleView.layoutIfNeeded()

   secondCircleView.layer.cornerRadius = secondCircleView.frame.size.width + 2
   secondCircleView.clipsToBounds = true
   secondCircleView.layoutIfNeeded()
   ```

Notes : You need to create out of both of views.

Prefer Screenshot :

[image]

Output:

[image]

Note1 : i have added it in UIView instead of it you can add it in UITableViewCell . I have used gray background color in first screenshot for understanding purpose. Please make it to white while running app.

Comment: Working solution i suppose, but it's still not solving the shadow-challenge :/ Thanks for your answer though!

Comment: @NicolaiHarbo What is the shadowing issue .Please explain so that I will solve that also. and if this solutions is working for you please accept this and up vote.

Comment: I need the shadow to follow the curve of the hole in the buttom.. Exactly like shown on the image :) But I solved my problem with using the image I posted here, and then my designer told me, that the green part was 20% of the length - then I created a transparent view on the white part that is 80% of the length, and another transparent view on the right part that is the last 20%, and then I'm able to add items and use the views to align the elements inside them :) But thanks alot for your effort mate! I really appreciate it!

Comment: @NicolaiHarbo You are welcome can you up vote my answer if it helps you